# How do i load a block correctly in Magento?

Tags: php, magento, module

I've ran into trouble while creating a module. The objective is simple, add a block to my module.

I know the xml file is loaded as it should, since it shows an error if i force it.

Module config:

```
<modules>
    <Cardfever_Product>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Cardfever_Product>
</modules>
```

Include layout:

```
 <layout>
        <updates>
            <product>
                <file>product.xml</file>
            </product>
        </updates>
 </layout>
```

My model include (inside global)

```
<blocks>
     <cardfever_product>
           <class>Cardfever_Product_Block</class>
     </cardfever_product>
</blocks>
```

My product.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
  <product_index_add>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="product/confirm" name="productadd" template="product/confirm.phtml" />
    </reference>
  </product_index_add>
</layout>
```

The controller are running and setup correctly at the url: product/index/add :

```
 public function AddAction()
 {
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->renderLayout();
 }
```

And finally my block code:

```
 class Cardfever_Product_Block_Confirm extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
 {
     public function methodblock()
     {
          return 'informations about my block !!' ;
     }
 }
```

Hope someone can help me out!

Answer (score 0):

In your layout use

```
<block type="cardfever_product/confirm" name="productadd" template="product/confirm.phtml" />
```

Comment: and you have to use `toHtml()` Method in your block not methodblock(). Or you call your method inside your template `product/confirm.phtml` via `$this->methodblock();`